# How to ensure changes to variables in .env file reflect in Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, environment-variables

I'm encountering an issue in my Django project where changes made to **variables in the .env file** do not seem to be reflected when I restart the server.

Here are the steps I've taken:

- Verified that the .env file is in the correct location and its name is exactly .env.
- Restarted the Django development server after making changes to the .env file.
- Double-checked the syntax of the .env file for any errors or typos.
- Cleared the cache after making changes to the .env fil (using `python manage.py clear_cache`)

Comment: just logged or print the .env  variables on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some packages to support `.env` files; like [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?
If not please install a package and add a code like this after setting `BASE_DIR` form the settings.py file:

```py
# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))
```

And after that, you can check the values loaded successfully like `print(os.environ.get("DB_NAME"))` and finally you can use the environment variables for your settings:

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME", "db_name"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER", "db_user"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD", "db_password"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT", "3306"),
    }
}
```

The second parameter from the `os.environ.get()` is the fallback values.

Comment: I'm not solely using .env files for environment variables. I am using environ. The problem I am facing is pertaining to the variable "BASE_URL".

Here's how I manage environment variables:
1. .env file: Initially defines BASE_URL.
2. envSetup.py: Reads .env file, sets up variables.
3. settings.py: Imports environment, assigns BASE_URL.

I have faced the same issue for another variable too, which I was using for pagination (items per page), then I had to use a different variable name to make the changes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details of your approach. I do not fully understand your intention but as I understand, Using .env files is ideal for static values, not dynamic ones like calculating BASE_URL for your Django project directory. For dynamic settings, consider using Django's settings or a custom config file alongside .env for more flexibility.